# Django fill table column based on subdict key

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dict in the following format:

```
{
  'P1': {'A': [1,10], 'B': [4,5], 'C': [8,12]},
  'P2': {'A': [1,10], 'E': [4,5], 'G': [8,12]},
  'P3': {'C': [1,10], 'D': [4,5], 'J': [8,12]}
}
```

and an HTML table set-up like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
.
.
.
```

what I'm trying to do is outputting the P's letter on the correct "cell", basically the data should go in the correct letter, like this:

```
Player | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
P1     | 1 | 4 | 8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
P2     | 1 |   |   |   | 4 |   | 8 |   |   |   |
P3     |   |   | 1 | 4 |   |   |   |   |   | 8 |
```

I tried this but failed:

```
{% for k,v in p_dataset.items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{k}}</td>
    {% for letter, vals in v.items %}
      <td>{% if letter == 'A' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'B' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'C' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'D' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'E' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'F' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'G' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'H' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'I' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if letter == 'J' %}{{vals}}{% endif %}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but all I got where a lot of exceeding tds, how should I do this?

*Edit:* Thinking about it, perhaps I could add all the subkeys as empty and update them on the view, but is there another way?

Comment: I would do the processing in the view, and thus check what columns are used, and then basically construct a list per row that contains *all* the columns, with `None`, or an empty string at the spots that are not filled in.

Comment: what about creating *alphabet list* in view and next in the template iterate over it, like: `{% for let in alphabet %} <td>{% if let == k %} {{ vals }} {% endif %} </td>{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chiefir for the idea, I ended up solving it like this:

```
{% for k,v in p_dataset.items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{k}}</td>
    <td>{% if v.A %}{{v.A|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.B %}{{v.B|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.C %}{{v.C|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.D %}{{v.D|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.E %}{{v.E|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.F %}{{v.F|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.G %}{{v.G|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.H %}{{v.H|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.I %}{{v.I|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if v.J %}{{v.J|join:' '}}%{% endif %}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor%}
```